# Alternatives to interpolate three dimensional data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that shows me a chemical concentration value based on temperature, pH and
ammonia. The way the I measure these variables, the ammonia level are always one of these six values (on top of the table), so it works as a categorical variable.

I need a way to interpolate on this table, based on these 3 variables. I tried using a combination of INDEX and MATCH, but I was not able to achieve what I wanted. Then I thought of "dividing" the table in intervals to "reduce" one variable and use an IF function to select which interval to interpolate based on the third variable (I was thinking pH or Ammonia), but I can't figure out a way to change intervals dynamically like this.

Can anyone think of an alternative to accomplish what I'm trying to do? If possible I would like to avoid using VBA, but if there is no other way I have no problem using it.

Thank you for the help!

I'm attaching an example of the table below.

[image: Snapshot of the table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that PH is in Column A:

```
=INDEX(A:H;MATCH(6,8;A:A;0)+MATCH(25;B:B;0)-2;MATCH(2;2:2,0))
```

Where the `-2` needs to be changed to the number of rows BEFORE the first `22` in `Temp`.

This also assumes that the pattern of `22;25;28` in `Temp` is the same for every `pH`

Comment: This formula works well to find the values in the table, but the problem is that the `Temp.` and `pH` values can be any value between the ones in the table, so I would need to interpolate to find the correct results.

Comment: Then remove the `,0` in the Matches for those two: `=INDEX(A:H;MATCH(6,8;A:A)+MATCH(25;B:B)-2;MATCH(2;2:2;0))`